# Concat and rename method with PHP

Tags: php, concatenation

I'm using PHP.
I don't understand why this works:

```
rename('C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\2.jpg','C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\1002.jpg');
```

While this doesn't work and I get this error: File cannot be found (code:2)

```
$i=2;
$tot=1002;
rename('C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\\'.$i.'.jpg','C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\\'.$tot.'.jpg');
```

Comment: Do you get an error or anything?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\'.$i.'.jpg' . I think the problem is extra '\'

Comment: You sure you didn't run the script already and the name is know 1002 not 2 ?

Comment: very strange cuz your code actually works fine.  http://codepad.org/SNf1Uji8

Comment: @CharlotteDunois   It's a warning

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what it says. Stack Overflow didn't give us crystal globes.

Comment: You should be using your code in a "loop" (`for` or `while`) and therefore the code you posted here will never generate the problem because the problem should be in your loop code.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you get one at 4k rep ;)

Comment: @Aimcorz Did you solved the problem now? If not you sure you didn't run the scipt already and the file name is 1002 not 2 ?

Comment: @Rizier123   Yes I solved it.

Comment: @Aimcorz And what was the error now?

Comment: @Rizier123  My code above works, should I delete this post? The error was caused by other lines of my script

Comment: @Aimcorz It's your choice. But if there wasn't anything nifty or something you had to fix, there is theoretical no answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Rizier123 comment if you run

```
rename('C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\2.jpg','C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\1002.jpg');
$i=2;
$tot=1002;
rename('C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\\'.$i.'.jpg','C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\\'.$tot.'.jpg');
```

in a single script, then the file C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\2.jpg has already been moved once and can't be found by the second `rename`.

Make sure the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\PF\IMG_DEX\2.jpg` exists and then run a script with only one `rename` function in it.

Comment: BTW: It's not every time bad to read the comments... Your answer was proposed 40min ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748535/concat-and-rename-method-with-php#comment43908361_27748535